# What happens when passing a numerical list to the rc parameter 'axes.facecolor' in python?

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I am looking at this example graph from Seaborn: https://seaborn.pydata.org/examples/kde_ridgeplot.html.

At the top of the block of code, they specify `rc={"axes.facecolor": (0, 0, 0, 0)}` to change matplotlib's facecolor rc-parameter. What does this do for the figure? Why a numerical list instead of a single color?

Comment: In the case of RGBA as the color specification format, each value is specified in tuple format. Kindly refer to [this](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.3/gallery/color/color_demo.html#sphx-glr-gallery-color-color-demo-py).

Comment: Great, this answered my question. Thank you very much!